# Deleting row in mysql with hibernate: Cannot delete or update a parent row

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two Classes, Fount and Criterions, the first one is one to many and the other many to one. When i call delete i get the error mentioned in the title.

I tried a lot of solutions here in stackoverflow and other sites about the same problem, but i can't do it right, i'll be glad if someone find out

Solutions i tried:

> Cascade - as you can see, i'm already using the annotation, and i tried a lot of different annotations that i found in the internet
>
> Remove the object Criterion from the object Fount and then the Fount from the Criterion before deleting the Criterion from the database
>
> Remove from Fount object and updating the database right after it

The error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`mydb`.`fount_criterion`, CONSTRAINT
> `FK5p3wsropwaokyta6cmy3edvcv` FOREIGN KEY (`criterions_id`) REFERENCES
> `criterion` (`id`))

my classes Fount and Criterion:

```
package br.com.engcon.entities;

import javax.persistence.*;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;
import org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "fount")
//@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQUENCE", sequenceName="fount_id_seq")
public class Fount {
    
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id; 
    
    @Column(nullable=false, name="url")
    private String url;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Criterion.class)
    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE})
    private List<Criterion> criterions;
//  
//  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Text.class, orphanRemoval = true)
//  @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE})
//  private List<Text> texts;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="isUsed")
    private boolean isUsed = false;

    @Column(nullable=false, name="isActive")
    private boolean isActive = true;
    
    @Column(nullable=false, name="isDeleted")
    private boolean isDeleted = false;

    public Fount(String url) throws URISyntaxException {
        this.url = url;
        this.criterions = new ArrayList<Criterion>();

        new URI(url);
    }
    
    public Fount(String url, List<Criterion> criterions) {
        this.url = url;
        this.criterions = criterions != null? criterions : new ArrayList<Criterion>();
    }
    
    public Fount() {
        this.criterions = new ArrayList<Criterion>();
    }
    
    public URI getURI() {
        if(!url.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                return new URI(url);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Criterion> getCriterions() {
        return criterions;
    }

    public void setCriterions(List<Criterion> criterions) {
        this.criterions = criterions;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    
    public void addCriterions(List<Criterion> criterions){
        this.criterions = this.criterions != null? this.criterions : new ArrayList<Criterion>();
        
        this.criterions.addAll(criterions);
    }
    
    public void addCriterions(Fount fount) {
        this.criterions = criterions != null? criterions : new ArrayList<Criterion>();
        
        for(Criterion criterion : fount.getCriterions()) {
            Criterion newCriterion = criterion.clone();
            
            newCriterion.setFount(this);
            
            criterions.add(newCriterion);
        }
    }

    public Criterion addCriterion(Criterion criterion) {
        this.criterions = criterions != null? criterions : new ArrayList<Criterion>();

        Criterion newCriterion = criterion.clone();
        newCriterion.setFount(this);
        
        this.criterions.add(newCriterion);

        return criterion;
    }

    public Criterion addCriterion(String criterionTxt) {
        return this.addCriterion(new Criterion(criterionTxt));
    }
    
    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getUrl();
    }

    public boolean isUsed() {
        return isUsed;
    }

    public void setUsed(boolean used) {
        isUsed = used;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        isActive = active;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }
}
```

Criterion:

```
package br.com.engcon.entities;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.ForeignKey;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

@Entity
@Table(name = "criterion")
//@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQUENCE", sequenceName="criterion_id_seq")
public class Criterion {
        
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name="fount_id", nullable=false)
    private Fount fount;
    
    @Column(nullable=true, name="word_filter")
    private String word;
    
    @Column(nullable=false, name="case_sensitive")
    private boolean caseSensitive;
    
    public Criterion() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        caseSensitive = false;
    }
    
    public Criterion(String word) {
        this.word = word;
        this.caseSensitive = false;
    }
    
    public Criterion(String word, boolean caseSensitive) {
        this.word = word;
        this.caseSensitive = caseSensitive;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Criterion clone(){
        return new Criterion(this.word, this.caseSensitive);
    }
    
    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public boolean isCaseSensitive() {
        return caseSensitive;
    }

    public void setCaseSensitive(boolean caseSensitive) {
        this.caseSensitive = caseSensitive;
    }

    public Fount getFount() {
        return fount;
    }

    public void setFount(Fount fount) {
        this.fount = fount;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.word;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [synchronize both end of the bidirectional association](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/).

If you have only 1 bidirectional association (in your example - Criterion-Fount and Fount-Criterion), the following helper methods (for disassociating the parent from all child entities) would solve the problem:

```
public void addCriterion(Criterion criterion) {
    criterions.add(comment);
    criterion.setFount(this);
}

public void removeCriterion(Criterion criterion) {
    criterions.remove(criterion);
    criterion.setFount(null);
}
```

And make sure you're using cascading:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "fount", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Criterion> criterions;
```

Comment: it worked when i removed the "nullable=false" attribute on Criterion annotation, that's bad? i mean, i shouldn't use this option?